# merge or synonym lvm and lvm2 tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Please can we merge or synonym the lvm and lvm2 tags?  On Linux, LVM1 is now obsolete so all questions will be about LVM2 in any case, and LVM is the general concept across operating systems.

https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/lvm2

https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/lvm

I only just realised there was an lvm2 tag because some questions are tagged with both.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [lvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/lvm) is the more popular tag, and we're not meant to include version numbers unless critical, so I'll merge them into [lvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/lvm)